# Too low voltage on digital input on attiny45

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, digital-logic, attiny, input

I'm using one of my attiny's pins as digital input. I am using a 2k2 pulldown resistor on the input. I am applying a simple square wave generated by a separate waveform generator. The high state for square wave is 5V, low is 0V.

However, when I look at the voltage on the digital input, voltage of high state is below 2V, while low state is 0V. My arduino doesnt detect high state as "1".

Does anyone has any idea why is it so?

Comment: Why do you think you need a pulldown?

Comment: Voltage divider with your pulldown?  And are you sure about your square wave from the output of your waveform generator?  It could be 2V there?

Comment: Post your code, as perhaps the pin is not defined as input, and it's set for output...  I'm not terribly familiar with the attiny. However, some uC's read the actual input state even when pins are defined as output.  Perhaps your generator is fighting the output pin state.

Comment: Also, what frequency is your generator set to?

Comment: The pin on the MCU may be configured wrong. Or, the output impedance of the generator and the pull-down resistor forms a 1:2.5 voltage divider.

Comment: Yep, pin was not defined as input. My stupid mistake. Thanks anyway:)